# Get remote system time from ICMP timestamp

Tags: ping, icmp, timestamp

I read from an article that ICMP Timestamp can be used to determine system time so I tried `hping3 192.168.1.x --icmp --icmp-ts -V`. The output shows

```
len=46 ip=192.168.1.x ttl=xx id=xxxx tos=0 iplen=40 icmp_seq=x rtt=x.xms
ICMP timestamp: Originate=27494134 Receive=27316024 Transmit=27316024
ICMP timestamp RTT tsrtt=xx
```

The problem is that I can't seem to make sense of the output...how do I derive the system time from the above results? Or am I doing something wrong here?

---

#### Solution

The timestamp of the remote host can be calculate from`Transmit=27316024`

1. Converting 27316024 milliseconds to hours, you get 7.59 hours
2. 7.59 hours translates to 07:35 Universal Time
3. Change the time according to your local time zone

#### Extras

**Timestamp** is the number of milliseconds since midnight, universal time.

`Originate` is the time that your local machine crafts the request packet
`Receive` is the time that the remote machine receives the packet
`Transmit` is the time that the remote machine crafts the response packet

Comment: try [nmap](https://nmap.org/) for detecting remote systems

Comment: @IporSircer I have tried `nmap -sn -A -vvv 192.168.1.x`. However, this only tells me that the host is up, it does not tell the current system time on that remote host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about the protocol and you will find this to be in the format of milliseconds since UT. https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0792.txt

Except for when the device can't provide this and the time is bogus - read the RFC. Clever trick but this will not be a reliable way to get time.